# Got an error while running "npm install" on angular-phonecat directory

Tags: angularjs, git, npm

Here is error message :

```
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall D:\prem\angular\angular-phonecat
> bower install
bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'
.npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\prem\angular\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have GIT installed on your machine. See also here: [cannot start angular-phonecat, postinstall script failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394533/cannot-start-angular-phonecat-postinstall-script-failing)

I cannot marked it as duplicate since the answer was not accepted on the other question.

Comment: But I have installed git and it working for other task

Comment: Maybe it is not in the path. It is quite clear in your log: `bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH`

Comment: Ok, you can see angular-phonecat is my root directory. If that is wrong path where should i install. Please help me it's killing me.

Comment: You need `git` binary in your path. Add it to your Windows PATH environment. Something like here: http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path You may need to adjust it a bit.